# how can i check a string like 'Submited' in a where condition using mysql

Tags: mysql

```
 $result2 = mysql_query( "SELECT  COUNT(Station_Name) AS sab1 FROM complaint_tbl WHERE Station_Name='".$sname."' and 
    Complaint_Type='".$cmbType."' and cmpsubtype='".$cmpsub."' and crimeloc='".$cmploc."' and Status= 'Submited' ");    
     while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result2))
     {
             $size1 = $row['sab1'];
     }
      mysql_free_result($result2);

     echo "Crimes solved yet:";
     echo $size1;
```

it is always showing an error like this  "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Submited' (T_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Crime\PoliceStation\Canalysersubmit.php on line 53"
how can i check a status with a string using mysql

Comment: This is perfectly correct SQL query, what type is column Status (VARCHAR)? BTW, since aggregation function COUNT() always returns one record you do not need to use while loop, instead just use one fetch

Comment: ok,i used varchar for status type

Comment: it is still s howing some errors like above

Comment: if you do not use debugger, put your sql query into $SQL variable and echo it instead of executing it in order to check it manually on DB.

Answer (score 0):

```
$SQL="SELECT COUNT(station_name)
        FROM complaint_tbl
       WHERE station_name='$sname'
         AND complaint_type='$cmbType'
         AND cmpsubtype='$cmpsub'
         AND crimeloc='$cmploc'
         AND status='Submited'";

//echo $SQL;

$rst=mysql_query($SQL);
$row=mysql_fetch_row($rst)
$size1=$row[0];

mysql_free_result($rst);

echo "Crimes solved yet:".$size1;
```